# Connect iPhone app to Desktop app

Tags: c#, iphone, wcf

In my C# project I have this function.

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something...");
}
```

In the application this can be called normally through an event, such as a button press. `DoStuff();`

I want to be able to call this function from an iPhone application, wirelessly.

I plan to do this by adding creating a TCP server in the C# Application that will listen for incoming connections. Then I can use my iphone to connect to my local ip, and the open port number, and then send a string of text to a console window, which will activate the function.

I understand this is not the best way to do this, but it is the only idea I have...

Some other things I have heard of are WCF? What is this and how can I use this to achieve my goal?

I know this question is quite general, but my programming experience is quite minimal.

Comment: As others have pointed out below, what you're looking for is most likely some sort of web serviced.  WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) can provide that, though it's primarily SOAP, and Web API can as well.  Web API is probably more suited to what you want to do.  Google either term and you'll get lots of information and tutorials.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I'll have a look at web api. Do you know of any examples that might help with my project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also use WCF which is natively in c# providing Webservice.

You can send soap message from iphone , let WCF do the left things and get soap response from WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean WCF provides a webservice? Does it setup a local server when the application is run? as the for soap message, I haven't heard of this before. Do you know of any documentation I can read from about it? Thanks.

Comment: @marcus To learn about SOAP. Refer to the link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/

Comment: To some extent,you can regard WCF as a web server.You can call it with parameters and get corresponding response just like you call a local method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific solvable problem and is opinion based. However, I'd look to web api instead of wcf.

You can run web app without IIS using the self host packages on nuget.

That gives you a http endpoint that is easier to interact with than wcf which invariably ends up being SOAP based. From IOS you're going to find this easier.

Just a pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really sure where to begin? How can I use this web api to recieve a command from my iphone to activate a function in my c# application?

Comment: Have a look at asp.net for tutorials. It is an alternative to wcf which for none windows clients has become very popular because the messages are much easier to construct. Because your calling from iOS you just need to make an http request to a URL to execute the code associated. There is a lot to cover but I think it'll be easier than the alternatives.